# C# Regex Formatting String without Input string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following Regex that is being used to matching incoming packets:

```
public static class ProtobufConstants
{
    public static Regex ContentTypeNameRegex => new Regex("application/protobuf; proto=(.*?)");
}
```

I also need to write outgoing packets strings in the same format, i.e. create strings similar to `"application/protobuf; proto=mynamespace.class1"` ideally by using the same regex definition `new Regex("application/protobuf; proto=(.*?)");`.

To keep this code in one place, is it possible to use this regex template and replace the `(.*?)` parameter with a string (as per above example i would like to substitute `"mynamespace.class1"`).

I see there is a `Regex.Replace(string input, string replacement)` but given the above `ContentTypeNameRegex` already has the format defined I don't have an input per se, I just want to format - not sure what to put here, if anything.

Is it possible to use in this manner, or do i need to revert to string.Format?

Comment: `public static Regex ContentTypeNameRegex(string protoPattern = ".*?")`?

Comment: Hi Ahmed thanks for the quick reply, have updated my question as may not have been clear

Comment: Check the updated answer below.

Comment: Regex is really not for formatting without an input.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to replace the matched group with something else, you can change your pattern to:

```
(application/protobuf; proto=)(.*?)
```

That way, you can replace it by doing something like:

```
Regex re = ContentTypeNameRegex;
string replacement = "mynamespace.class1";
re.Replace(input, "$1" + replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Regex.Replace` but use the match evaluator to handle your *formatting* needs. Here is an example which simply replaces a slash with a dash and visa versa, based on what has been matched.

```
var text = "001-34/323";

Regex.Replace(text, "[-/]", me => { return me.Value == "-" ? "/" : "-";   })
```

**Result**

```
001/34-323
```

You can do the same with your input, to decide to change it or send it on as is.